# Generate date_time from date only column

Tags: sql-server

How do I generate a date_time out of just date only column. For instance I have 8/31/2013 and I want to sequence the hour ending from 1...24 hours like below

(I need Table A to be like this)

```
8/31/2013 12:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 1:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 2:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 3:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 4:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 5:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 6:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 7:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 8:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 9:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 10:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 11:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 12:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 1:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 2:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 3:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 4:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 5:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 6:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 7:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 8:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 9:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 10:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 11:00:00 PM
9/1/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Cross join a table full of times. You can make your own from any numbers table if you needed (e.g. `SELECT CAST(myDateTable.DateCol AS DATETIME) + T.myTime FROM (SELECT myTime = CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, number, '00:00.000') AS TIME) FROM master..spt_values WHERE type='P' AND number < 24) AS T CROSS JOIN myDateTable`)

Answer (score 0):

Following code:

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATETIME, @Date2 DATETIME
SET @Date1 = '2013-08-30 11:00:00'
SET @Date2 = '2013-08-30 23:00:00'

SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,number+1,@Date1) [Date]
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(HOUR,number+1,@Date1) < @Date2
```

Will result as:

[image]

Is that what you are looking for? I'm sure you can work out the `AM/PM` in the presentation layer.

**EDIT**

And if you need `AM/PM` time, following should work for you:

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATETIME, @Date2 DATETIME
SET @Date1 = '2013-08-30 11:00:00'
SET @Date2 = '2013-08-30 23:00:00'

SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR, DATEADD(HOUR,number+1,@Date1), 101)+' '+LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(HOUR,number+1,@Date1), 100), 7)) AS [Date]
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(HOUR,number+1,@Date1) < @Date2
```

- You can further use this result set to cross apply with your table.
- And you can use the date2 as a calculated value too.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I need to derive this using getdate(). my query Date>= DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) and date< DATEADD(day, +0, convert(date, GETDATE()))
almost works, but not sure why it is starting from hour 1. How do I start this from 12:00 am. 7/24/2017 1:00:00.000 AM
7/24/2017 2:00:00.000 AM...........and so forth